# what is parse error in update panel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, parsing, updatepanel

Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' does not have a public property named 'script'.

```
    <!--modal start-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="Addmodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a href="csuv3.aspx" class="btn btn-link" style="float:right">X</a>
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:red">Add</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="auto-style10"  style="margin-top:11px; margin-bottom:7px;">
            <p><u>Don't Leave Empty Field Please Fill 'N.A' There !! <b> : </b></u><br /><br />

            </p>
            <table style="float:right;">
                 <tr>
                        <td class="table">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="table">



                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender0" PopupButtonID="TextBox1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
                </cc1:CalendarExtender>  
                <%-- <asp:TextBox ID="dtpTransDate" runat="server" Width="90px"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp1:CalendarExtender ID="dtpTransDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="dtpTransDate">
                 </asp1:CalendarExtender>--%>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" Text="Start Time"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="dllstarttime" runat="server" Style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: xx-small"
                                Width="150px" CssClass="dropdown">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="0:00" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="7:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="7:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="8:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="8:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="9:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="9:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="10:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="10:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="11:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="11:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="12:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="12:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="13:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="13:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="14:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="14:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="15:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="15:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="16:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="16:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="17:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="17:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="18:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="18:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="19:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="19:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="20:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="20:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="21:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="21:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="22:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="22:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="23:00"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtday" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                           <%-- <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dllstarttime"
                                ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="0:00" ValidationGroup="s+u" ForeColor="#FF0066"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" Text="End Time"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlendtime" runat="server" Style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: xx-small"
                                Width="150px" CssClass="dropdown">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="0:00" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="7:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="7:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="8:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="8:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="9:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="9:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="10:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="10:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="11:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="11:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="12:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="12:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="13:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="13:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="14:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="14:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="15:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="15:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="16:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="16:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="17:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="17:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="18:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="18:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="19:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="19:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="20:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="20:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="21:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="21:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="22:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="22:30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="23:00"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlendtime"
                                ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="0:00" ValidationGroup="s+u" ForeColor="#FF0066"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblhrs" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" text-align="Right" runat="server" Text="ID"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="Comname"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="rldlstcomname" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rldlstcomname_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                CssClass="dropdown">
                                 <asp:ListItem Text="<-Select->" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rldlstcomname"
                                ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="&lt;-Select-&gt;" ValidationGroup="s+u" ForeColor="#FF0066"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Brand_Name"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="rldlstbrand" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" AutoPostBack="True"
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="rldlstbrand_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                 <asp:ListItem Text="<-Select->" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Zone"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlZone" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlZone_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                AutoPostBack="True">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="<-Select->" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>

                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlZone"
                                ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="&lt;-Select-&gt;" ValidationGroup="s+u" ForeColor="#FF0066"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Location"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddllocation" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddllocation_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="<-Select->" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Program"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtprogram" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Venue Name"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtVenueName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Venue"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtvenue" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="VenueEmail"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtvenueEmail" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="VenueMobile"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtvenuemob" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="VenueContactPerson"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtconperson" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="AddtionalName"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddname" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="AddtionalMobile"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddmob" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="VenueVendorEmail"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtvenuevendoremail" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="VenueVendorMobile"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtvenuevendormob" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="VenueVendorName"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtvenuevendorname" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="deletebtn" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-link" Text="Yes" Width="153px" Visible="false"/></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnno" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-link" Text="No" Width="153px" Visible="false"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <!--modal end-->
        </asp:UpdatePanel> 
Need the answer as soon as possible
thanks in advance
```

Comment: Looks nice : `Need the answer as soon as possible`, I'm pretty doubt about what you are thinking about SO.

Comment: @un-lucky I don't understand what u said

Comment: Make sure your detail view should wrapped inside `ContentTemplate` tag. I experienced similar problem when using web forms some years ago and found that I missed `ContentTemplate` before adding editors and HTML layouts.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thanks sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my past experience, all HTML tags and other editor server controls that work inside UpdatePanel must be enclosed by ContentTemplate property tag:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdPanel" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<div class="modal fade" id="Addmodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a href="csuv3.aspx" class="btn btn-link" style="float:right">X</a>
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:red">Add</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="auto-style10"  style="margin-top:11px; margin-bottom:7px;">
            <p><u>Don't Leave Empty Field Please Fill 'N.A' There !! <b> : </b></u><br /><br />
            </p>
            <table style="float:right;">
            <%-- simplified for brevity --%>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If you have ScriptManager tag before UpdatePanel, make sure UpdatePanel placed outside the tag, since you should not put any tags inside ScriptManager control.